# Learning R - Error in Import No Such File

Tags: r, import, importerror

I am new to R, and I am following certain tutorials in the process. 
Whenever I Run/press the execute key (Cmd + Enter) on this code:

```
df <- import("data/StateData.xlsx") %>%
```

I automatically get this error:

```
Error in import("data/StateData.xlsx") : No such file
```

Please advise as to why this problem is happening. These codes are already written as I am using exercise file and I am following exactly the same way as shown in the video.

I have manually attempted to import data, but result is same,

Please advise, why it's giving me this error and how I can fix it.

Screenshot:

[image]

Many Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have a folder called `data` that contains the file `StateData.xlsx`?

Comment: I seems that you're already in the directory "data", so you don't need "data" in your path, just try `import("StateData.xlsx")`. You can get your current directory with `getwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Commenters starja & Andrew were pointing you in the correct direction. Here's a little more detail with explicit instructions.

Your R console is always in a specific directory, called the working directory. You must pass a valid path to your import function that tells it where StateData.xlsx is on your computer. This could be a relative path to your working directory or an absolute path on your hard drive (like c:...).

Note also that I have not used the function "importdata" before, I typically use read.table and it's family of function to import local files into R.

type

```
getwd()
```

to see what directory your console is in.

```
dir()
```

or

```
list.files()
```

will give a a list of files in your consoles current directory.

```
list.dirs()
```

Will give a list of sub-directories that are inside your console's current directory.

You can get a lot more info about the above file system function or any R function by entering ? followed by the function name without the parentheses:

```
?list.dirs
```

On my windows computer, with base R, assuming I used the importdata function, I could simply start typing the function importdata(' and then the tab key to access the autofill capabilities of the console to fill in the pathname to the file. After finishing typing the relative file path, end with ') and press enter.

Whether you type the path by hand, or use autocomplete, as soon as you have a valid path the error should clear and your dataframe df should be populated from the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems finding files in your analysis, it can be easier to use the familiar point and click from your operating system. In that case you can replace your import with the command

```
import(choose.files())
```

which brings up a window to find the file you're looking for.

Alternatively you can use `choose.files()` to locate the file once, and then copy and paste the path that it returns into your script so that it is reproducible.